# how to send a file from server to client by running ant script at client

Tags: ant, file-transfer

Whenever we run an ant script in client machine it has to zip the build files in server and has to be received at client.
Can we use FTP?

Answer (score 1):

Ant provides an [FTP task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html) and an [SCP task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) which you can use to transfer files.